# How can I increase the height of the bokeh toolbar?

Tags: python, css, bokeh, toolbar, figure

I am using Bokeh to create a webpage with tabs and figures.
On one tab there is a map.  I would like to increase the size of the toolbar (which is above the map) so it's more obvious for users that there is a toolbar there and they can use the tools to zoom etc.

Hopefully this is obvious but I've searched for over an hour and haven't found anything.
Possibly it's in the docs under toolbar  I'm still learning python and have difficultly understanding the Bokeh instructions and couldn't find anything though.... thanks!!

p.s. I'm using Bokeh version 3.1.0, I've managed to make the tab sizes bigger using a stylesheet, maybe that would work somehow on the toolbar too?  If there's some way to also change the icon colours that would be great too. Just want to make them more obvious.

Comment: At the moment this is not supported but there is already work in process ([#13189](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/13189)) to make it possible. Some other elements can already be styled using `InlineStyleSheet`, see the section in the docs about [Stylesheets](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/3.1.1/docs/user_guide/styling/dom.html).

Comment: cool, thank you very much for letting me know, I'll have a look at the other elements then and see if there's anything else I can do to make it more obvious.